# How to inject xss attack string in dropdown of web page?

Tags: html, xss, penetration-testing, zap

I found one XSS vulnerability in my website. I am using ZAP for vulnerability scanning.
from ZAP I found an alert which shows alert for `"><script>alert(1);</script>`  string.

And path it has mentioned is a registration page of my website. There are couple of drop downs present on that page.

For example: in drop down of selecting country I have kept options of all countries.
and "No match found" for wrong text.

If i want to execute XSS on that drop down , when I enter string `"><script>alert(1);</script>`

it gives error "No Match found",

Can you tell me how I can successfully get alert when I enter string `"><script>alert(1);</script>`?

Comment: Try using `\x3e` instead of the `<` key.

Comment: Hi , i tried using \x3e instead of < key but its not working.
the string i am entering through ZAP is 
"><script>alert(1);</script>

Comment: Any inputs for this?

Comment: It's quite difficult to tell where an XSS vulnerability is in code we don't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

```
\x3escript>alert("XSS");\x3e/script>
```

Comment: Would you mind to review your answer? The `\x3e` looks strange to me

Comment: I tried using give code i.e. \x3escript>alert("XSS");\x3e/script>
but when i put this string in drop down it give me "No Match Found"
Is there is any special way to inject this code?
Like tamper data or something ?